Image cannot be edited after adding to TUI Image Editor
The image cannot be edited after being added to TUI Image Editor.  The image is active and moving. There are checkpoints. But they are not active. I forcibly turned them on but to no avail. When several images are added to the canvas, they can be selected with the mouse and after that the points begin to work
 fabric.Image.fromURL(imagepath, (img) => {
        // Настраиваем параметры изображения, например, позицию и масштаб
        img.set({
          left: 100, // X-позиция
          top: 100, // Y-позиция
          scaleX: 1, // Масштаб по оси X
          scaleY: 1, // Масштаб по оси Y
          selectable: true // Делаем объект редактируемым и перемещаемым
        })
        console.log(img)
        // Добавляем изображение на холст
        canvas.add(img)

        // Делаем объект активным для редактирования
        canvas.setActiveObject(img)

        // Обновляем холст, чтобы отображались изменения
        canvas.renderAll()
      })

I tried adding an image both through addImageObject in TUI and directly in fabric.js fabric.Image.fromURL. After loading JSON the problem remains
